# Como criar uma nova janela para cada botão clicado?

Tags: java, android

Olá, sou iniciante em programação pra android, e estou fazendo um aplicativo (trabalho do curso TI).

É o seguinte: a primeira Activity tem 12 botões com background de "mesas", representando as mesas de um restaurante. Ao clicar, deverá abrir uma janela para inserir os dados do cliente da respectiva mesa.

Exemplo: Pessoas (Quantidade), pedidos a serem feitos, preço total.
Só que eu tenho 12 Botões (mesas), eu teria que criar 12 Activity com Layouts para cada mesa? Eu acho que isso iria pesar. Existe algum modo de fazer isso melhor ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

(Depois de informado os dados da mesa, irá confirmar nessa janela única de cada mesa, e a mesa mudará de background para uma imagem da mesa de cor cinza, sinalizando que ja tem cliente.)

Comment: Só é necessário uma Activity ou, eventualmente melhor, um DialogFragment.

Comment: Entendi, mas se eu voltar dessa janela, exemplo, a janela da mesa 1, clicar na mesa 2, inserir os dados nela, as da mesa 1 nao irão se perder ne ? Pois isso nao pode acontecer.

Comment: Terá de criar um sistema para guardar os dados de cada mesa, ele pode ser um simples ArrayList ou um banco de dados.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso com um dialog.

Na criação do dialog você precisa definir um layout em que será solicitados as informações que você deseja solicitar a respeito de cada mesa. Abaixo segue um exemplo que pode te auxiliar a resolver o seu problema.
**dialog_layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:hint="Valor"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" /></LinearLayout>
```

Na classe ou fragment em que você deseja inflar o dialog você deve adicionar o seguinte código:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            // Get the layout inflater
            final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
            // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
            // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
            builder.setView(v)
                    // Add action buttons
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           String valorDigitado = ((EditText) v).getText().toString();
                            showToast();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            break;
```

Quando for clicado em confirmar(setPositiveButton) você deve buscar todos os dados que foram preenchidos;

Para salvar suas informaçoes você pode criar um ArrayList da classe Mesa do seguinte modo:

```
ArrayList<Mesa> mesa = new ArrayList<Mesa>()
```

Então toda vez que uma for clicado em confirmar você deve criar um objeto mesa e adiciona-lo, suponhamos que mesa tenha os campos total e gorjeta então teríamos:

```
public class Mesa{
private String valor;
private String gorjeta;
public String getGorjeta(){
  return this.gorjeta;
}
public void setGorjeta(String gorjeta){
   this.gorjeta = gorjeta;
}
public String getValor(){
  return this.valor;
}
public void setValor(String valor){
   this.valor = valor;
}

}
```

Então você faria o seguinte:

```
Mesa m = new Mesa();
m.setValor("valor que sera obtido do dialog como no exemplo dessa resposta");
m.setGorjeta("valor que sera obtido do dialog como no exemplo dessa resposta");
mesa.add(posicaodoClick,m);
```

o valor posicaoClick você obtem através do metodo setOnItemClickListener que te dará a posição que foi clicado, isto se faz necessário para que você mantenha o controle da qual posição que foi clicada, creio que você esteja usando um gridView então seria algo do tipo:

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {
       //chama dialog;
       //preenche objeto do tipo mesa
       //insere no ArrayList de Mesa
       //mesa.add(position,objetoTipoMesa);
    }
});
```

Comment: Só falta a forma de partilhar o `ArrayList<Mesa>` entre a *Activity* e o *Dialog*

Comment: Eu ainda nao entendo MUITO sobre, mas você deu uma perfeita explicação cara. Estou começando agora, e as vezes as coisas nao fica claro pra mim. MUITO obrigado cara.. exatamente o que eu queria =)

Comment: @NilzonMartins Boa tarde, se a resposta lhe resolveu o problema marque-a como correta por favor. Se não sabe como fazer então leia isto: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635 - Obrigado